# Understanding why Roots of Chebyshev Polynomial Give best Interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods

So I know that if we choose the nodes of the interpolating polynomial to be the roots of the Chebyshev polynomial then the error is minimized. My textbook doesn't fully prove this, they just give a sketch of the proof.

In the sketch they mention $\int_{-1} ^{1} |(x-x_0) \cdot\cdot\cdot (x-x_n)| dx =2^{-n} $ and give no hint as to how they got here.

I know that we get this by integrating both sides of the usual error statement for interpolating polynomials. I think the rest of the proof mainly makes sense but this step has me stumped.

I tried to use induction to prove this to myself but it wasn't working. Maybe I made a silly mistake, but I can't seem to find my error and I cannot find anything on this on the internet. Can someone please give me a hint on how to prove this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing absolute sign *and it should be max not integral*, i.e.
$$
\max_{x\in[-1,1]}\lvert (x-x_0)\dots(x-x_n)\rvert=\max_{x\in[-1,1]}\lvert 2^{-n}T_{n+1}(x)\rvert=2^{-n}.
$$

**Edit**: correcting not integral.
The formula for error of polynomial interpolation with nodes $x_i$, $i=0,1,\dots,n$ is
$$
f(x)-P_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}\prod_{i=0}^n (x-x_i)
$$
so the maximum error is never more than $\sup\frac1{(n+1)!}\lvert f^{(n+1)}\rvert$ when using Chebyshev nodes.

Comment: thank you! You are correct I will edit it. Can you please explain the result a bit more?

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful

Comment: Very quick follow up question. I get that you took a change of variable and that's how the bounds of the integral changed to pi's but should it have been $|cos((n+1) \theta)|$ inside the integral?

Comment: Also now that I'm looking at it should the bounds of the integral after the substitution be $\pi$ to $0$?

Comment: That makes sense. Is there some way to prove the integral though? That's really what I need to understand the proof I'm going through

Comment: Sorry the integral doesn't work: $\int_{-1}^1 \lvert T_2\rvert=\frac23(2\sqrt2-1)$ and without the absolute sign we have $\int_{-1}^1 T_n=\frac{1+(-1)^n}{1-n^2}$ if $n\neq 1$.

Comment: I think I may see the problem. You tried to use the definition of Chebyshev of the 1st kind. Now that I look closer at the proof I believe they are referring  to Chebyshev of the 2nd kind. Does this change things? Sorry about that!

Comment: That does.  So you want $U$ instead of $T$ which works because $\int_{-1}^1\lvert U_n(x)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x=2$ from $\int_0^\pi \lvert U_n(\cos(\theta))\rvert\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta$.  The integrand is $\lvert\sin((n+1)\theta)\rvert$ which we know the integral on every $\pi/(2(n+1))$ intervals starting at $0$, and the leading coefficient of $U_{n+1}$ is $2^{n+1}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I get it now.